# How do you change the time zone of the server to match local?

Tags: azerothcore

Running AC in Docker and cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the server time to match local. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this but I'm pretty sure timezone is set within the "dockerfile" under:
\azerothcore-wotlk\apps\docker

There are multiple instances that need to be set for each container (if that's the right word).

```
# set timezone environment variable
ENV TZ=Etc/UTC
```

So if you want EST you should just be able to change UTC to EST.

I was also trying to change it directly within CLI for each of the docker containers.  I believe timezone is set in:

```
etc/utc/timezone
```

Unfortunately I don't think this is editable.  I couldn't find a text editor installed and I think there are protections in place limiting edits to the settings.  Probably the best bet would be to edit the dockerfile above and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing as you suggested and it had no effect. I did some more digging and proper timezone for me should be America/Chicago for Central US time zone, however, after updating all those entries in the dockerfile, it still has UTC on the server. I have restarted the server since making the changes to the dockerfile, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you do a full rebuild or, just server restart? I think those settings would only be applied through doing a rebuild, or maybe even starting with a fresh install.

Comment: It could be that there's more than one place that the setting is originating from too.  You could try getting Notepad++ which has a Find text function to scan through all files in a directory (think it might be called a search Project in the context of the software).  You could try searching for timezone or UTC and seeing which files have the settings, and changing all of them. This worked for me when I was trying to understand why I couldn't change the server password easily where several files made reference to hardcoded passwords.

Comment: I did a full rebuild, not just a restart. I may try scouring the files for UTC and see what I can find. :)